# How to stop insertion of Duplicate documents in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

Let us have a `MongoDB` collection which has three docs..

db.collection.find()

```
 { _id:'...', user: 'A', title: 'Physics',   Bank: 'Bank_A' }
 { _id:'...', user: 'A', title: 'Chemistry', Bank: 'Bank_B' }
 { _id:'...', user: 'B', title: 'Chemistry', Bank: 'Bank_A' }
```

We have a doc,

```
 doc = { user: 'B', title: 'Chemistry', Bank:'Bank_A' }
```

If we use

```
 db.collection.insert(doc)
```

here, this duplicate doc will get inserted in database.

```
 { _id:'...', user: 'A', title: 'Physics',   Bank: 'Bank_A' }
 { _id:'...', user: 'A', title: 'Chemistry', Bank: 'Bank_B' }
 { _id:'...', user: 'B', title: 'Chemistry', Bank: 'Bank_A' }
 { _id:'...', user: 'B', title: 'Chemistry', Bank: 'Bank_A' }
```

How this duplicate can be stopped. On which field should indexing be done or any other approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongodb avoid duplicate entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191311/mongodb-avoid-duplicate-entries)

Comment: @John Petrone : here, we can not do indexing on a particular field, as value of fields are repeating.
{unique:true} will create problem.

Comment: Use a compound index http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-compound-index/

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Don't use insert.

Use [update with `upsert=true`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). Update will look for the document that matches your query, then it will modify the fields you want and then, you can tell it upsert:True if you want to insert if no document matches your query.

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
  {
    upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
    writeConcern: <document>
   }
  )
```

So, for your example, you could use something like this:

```
db.collection.update(doc, doc, {upsert:true})
```

Comment: Be aware that upsert can be dangerous if you expect to be priming a document for first use, since it will happily wipe out anything that is stored there, in favor of the upserted values. The pattern that John P. proposed is a better general answer for avoiding duplicate records, though either approach would be adequate for the simple case presented where the compound key would include all existing document fields. If you consider the very commonly needed addition of a 'creation time' for the record, you can see how this breaks down for many general cases...

Comment: I humbly request everyone to refer John Petrone's answer too !!

Answer (score 67):

You should use a compound index on the set of fields that uniquely identify a document within your MongoDB collection. For example, if you decide that the combination of user, title and Bank are your unique key you would issue the following command:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { user: 1, title: 1, Bank: 1 }, {unique:true} )
```

Please note that this should be done after you have removed previously stored duplicates.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-compound-index/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Comment: @Roberto ensureIndex creates the index if it doesn't exist already

Comment: Oh, you're right @Azmisov, but ensureIndex was actually deprecated since 3.0, now it's a (deprecated) alias for createIndex, as 3.0 did not exist when this answer was created I'm removing my downvote :) (it doesn't allow me to undo my downvote until the answer is edited, let's hope John Petrone adds this as an update...

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed and confirmed working after trying to insert the same item. It now throws an error properly.

Answer (score 7):

It has been updated from the above answers.

please use `db.collection.updateOne()` instead of `db.collection.update()`.
and also `db.collection.createIndexes()` instead of `db.collection.ensureIndex()`

Update: 
the methods update() and ensureIndex() has been deprecated from mongodb 2.*, you can see more details in [mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) and the path is `./mongodb/lib/collection.js`. 
For `update()`, the recommend methods are `updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite`.
For `ensureIndex()`, the recommend method is `createIndexes`.

Comment: Why should these options be preferred? Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: as far as I can see, for `update`, it just redesigned the response object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a bit slower than other ways but it works too. It can be used inside a loop:

```
db.collection.replaceOne(query, data, {upsert: true})
```

The query may be something like:

```
{ _id: '5f915390950f276680720b57' }
```

*https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne*

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `AddToSet` instead of `Push` or `Insert`.
Using the `Upsert` flag dosen't seem to work for me.

ie: `var updateSet = Builders<T>.Update.AddToSet(collectionField, value);`

Note that `AddToSet` seems to do a value comparison.

Answer (score 0):

setting your document's _id key to be the unique identifier and using collection.insert_many(documents, ordered=False) will both allow you to bulk insert and simultaneously prevent duplicates.

eg.

documents = [{'_id':'hello'}, {'_id':'world'}, {'_id':'hello'}]

collection.insert_many(documents, ordered=False)

ordered=False is important.  according to the documentation, if ordered=True then mongo will stop attempting to insert if it encounters an duplicate _id.  If ordered=False, mongo will attempt to insert all documents.