# How to prevent duplicates in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo "insert_one",
I want to prevent insertion of two documents with the same "name" attribute.

1. How do I generally prevent duplicates?
2. How do I config it for a specific attribute like name?

Thanks!

My code:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:8888/db')
db = client[<db>]
heights=db.heights

post_id= heights.insert_one({"name":"Tom","height":2}).inserted_id


try:
    post_id2 = heights.insert_one({"name":"Tom","height":3}).inserted_id

except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError, e:
    print e.error_document

print post_id
print post_id2
```

output:

56aa7ad84f9dcee972e15fb7

56aa7ad84f9dcee972e15fb8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an index that ensures the name is unique in that collection

e.g.

```
db.heights.create_index([('name', pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)
```

Please see [the official docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#indexing) for further details and clarifying examples

Answer (score 6):

There is an answer for preventing addition of duplicate documents in mongoDB in general at [How to stop insertion of Duplicate documents in a mongodb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122981/how-to-stop-insertion-of-duplicate-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection) .

The idea is to use `update`  with `upsert=True` instead of `insert_one`. 
So while inserting the code for pymongo would be

```
db[collection_name].update(document,document,upsert=True)
```

Comment: This command shows an error 
db[collection_name].update(document,document,upsert=True)

Answer (score 2):

This is your document

```
doc = {"key": val}
```

Then, use `$set` with your document to update

```
update = {"$set": doc} # it is important to use $set in your update
db[collection_name].update(document, update, upsert=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem myself and couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

Eventually I came up with the idea of

1. searching the collection for the exact data I was going to put into it
2. count the number of results
3. If the number of results is 1 the data already exists, if the number is 0 it doesn't.

This is working for what I was looking for, maybe iz helps others:

```
# dummy data we want to insert to MongoDB
json_data = '{"location": "Berlin","date": 2023,"temperature": 19, "clouds": true}'

# Connect to collection
db = client[event["database"]]
collection = db[event["collection"]]

# Check if the data already exists
cursor = collection.find(json_data)
# If no objects are returned store the data
if(len(list(cursor)) == 0): collection.insert_one(json_data)
```