# Why does mongoose still allow duplicate entries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema set up like this :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UrlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  url_name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    index: true
  },
  url_address: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    index: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Url', UrlSchema);
```

From my understanding (Im a beginner), the `unique`, `required` and `index` options mean that no duplicate entries are allowed into the database. However, this is not the case here. I set up a simple API that takes in the request body and adds it to mongo database.

Here is the request body:

```
{
    "url_name":"testing",
    "url_address":"111.11.1.11"
}
```

However, I can add this same body multiple times without the duplicate error showing up. Any idea why?

Comment: First thing to check - are the entries definitely being persisted to the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop insertion of Duplicate documents in a mongodb collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122981/how-to-stop-insertion-of-duplicate-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: @JoeClay the data is added into the database correctly