# Is there a way in mongodb to have insertOne fail to create duplicate indexed documents without throwing an error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wanted to avoid creating duplicate documents, so upon searching how to do this, the first solution I found was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24125275/9400421):

```
db.collection.update(doc, doc, {upsert:true})
```

But this is really slow compared to `insertOne`, so I looked to the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24123426/9400421):

```
db.collection.createIndex( { propertyName: 1 }, {unique:true} )
```

This seems like a way better solution in terms of performance, but the problem is rather than just not inserting the duplicate, it throws an error:

`(node:97200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: main.dir index: path_1 dup key: { propertyName: "propertyName123" }`

Is there a setting to make it not throw an error or do I need to use a try catch here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible - if you take a look at the NodeJS MongoDB-driver source you can see that `insertOne` uses the [underlying method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/lib_collection.js.html#line516) `executeOperation`.

This method has a try catch around its actual execution of the statement and re-throws any error that might occur as you can see [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/operations/execute_operation.js#L85). So afaik there's no way to "suppress" errors - you need to handle them yourself.