# How to insert multiple documents at once in MongoDB while skipping documents with duplicate fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using the native Node.js MongoDB driver to insert multiple documents at once. I have an array of javascript objects (where each object represents a user), and I am using the following code.

```
var col = db.collection('users');
col.insertMany(usersArray, function(err, r) {
    if (err) {
       log('Bulk Insert Error', err);
    } else {
       log('Successful Insert', r.insertedCount);
       db.close();
    }
});
```

Each user document in the `usersArray` array has an email field. I do not want to insert objects where a document with the email already exists in the `users` collection, as I have modelled emails to be unique. Such documents should be skipped in the query.

I know this would be achievable if `usersArray` had an `_id` field (where I would use `continueOnError: true`), but unfortunately my `usersArray` is from a separate source. Doing single inserts is inefficient, as my `usersArray` can have well over ~1000 objects.

The work around I have thought of is selecting all documents from db and reconstructing the `usersArray` with only unique documents in my node application, to reduce the number of requests to MongoDB. Is there a way the `collection.insertMany()` function can be modified to do this? Raw MongoDB queries will also be appreciated.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191311/mongodb-avoid-duplicate-entries