# Spring data MongoDB - Insert batch skip duplicates

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to save 1000+ entries in batch, ignoring the duplicates

```
@Document("contacts")
@Data
@CompoundIndex(name = "unique_name_number", unique = true, def = "{'name' : 1, 'phoneNumber' : 1 }")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ContactModel {

    @Id
    String id;

    Instant createdAt;
    String name;
    String phoneNumber;

}
```

And the execution

```
MongoTemplate mongo;
List<ContactModel> contacts = getLongList()
mongo.insert(contacts, ContactModel.class)
```

This code throws an exception if there are duplicates (name,phoneNumber).

How can I tell to mongo

**Skip the duplicates and continue to insert the rest?**

Thanks much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb avoid duplicate entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191311/mongodb-avoid-duplicate-entries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try, using an unordered `BulkOperations`, like this:

```
BulkOperations bulkOps = mongo.bulkOps(BulkMode.UNORDERED, ContactModel.class);
bulkOps.insert(contacts);
BulkWriteResult result;
try {
   result = bulkOps.execute();
} catch(BulkOperationException e) {
   // exception triggers after the operation is completed in case of duplicates
   result = e.getResult();
}
```

The `BulkOperationException` also contains information about errors (and categories)

```
List<BulkWriteError> errors = e.getErrors();
```