# How to specify a field in an embedded document inside a list to be globaly unique

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I want to create a list of embedded document, and having a specific field in each embedded document to be unique not only on the list, but on all lists in the entire collection.

So I did this:

```
class User(Document):
    emails = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Email))

class Email(EmbeddedDocument):
    email = StringField(unique=True) # This doesn't work!
    verified = BooleanField(default=False)
```

This just doesn't work, I still can add duplicate mail, either to the same user, or across users!
Please help, thanks.

Comment: You probably want to run the ensureIndex() function in pymongo to make a unique index on `emails.email`, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912661/pymongo-mongodb-create-index-or-ensure-index

Answer (score 0):

The uniqueness in an index with MongoDB is enforced per document, not per element in an array. If you want to enforce that, you have to split out those documents into a separate collection.