# ensure_index with key_or_list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to install this software, a few scripts for searching in a local mongodb database:
https://github.com/wimremes/cve-search/blob/master/README.md

Since the search.py script fail miserably, I'm trying to put some index as suggested:

```
db.cpe.ensureIndex( {id:1 } )
db.cves.ensureIndex( {id:1} )
db.cves.ensureIndex( {vulnerable_configuration:1} )
db.vfeed.ensureIndex( {id:1} )
```

But this code is not working: ensureIndex fail with this error:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pymongo/collection.py", line 1672, in __call__
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'ensureIndex' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

and `ensure_index( {id:1})` return this:

```
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
```

What shoud I do for ceating new indexes?

Comment: db.cpe.create_index( "id") is working, but i don't know if has the same effect.

Comment: what driver are you using? pymongo?

Comment: yes! the driver used in the cve-search software.

Comment: I'm not into python/pymongo, but there is already a topic here featuring create_index vs ensure_index http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912661/pymongo-mongodb-create-index-or-ensure-index

Comment: Yes i know perfectly the difference thanks to that post. :)  This is matter of parameters, i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written is in Javascript syntax. In Python using PyMongo, the same operations look like:

```
db.cpe.ensure_index( {'id':1 } )
db.cves.ensure_index( {'id':1} )
db.cves.ensure_index( {'vulnerable_configuration':1} )
db.vfeed.ensure_index( {'id':1} )
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually, in PyMongo they would look like this:

```
db.collection.ensure_index([("id", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

You can read more in the [PyMongo Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.ensure_index).

---

**Update:** In version 3.0 and above `ensure_index` [has been removed](http://api.mongodb.org/python/3.0/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.ensure_index). You should now use `create_index` instead. For more info, see the docs for the [JavaScript library](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/).

You can also read about `ensure_index` vs `create_index` here: [Pymongo / MongoDB: create index or ensure index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912661/pymongo-mongodb-create-index-or-ensure-index?lq=1)

Comment: The documentation links to pymongo 3.0 . Does it work with 3.2 . Its not working for me.

Comment: @AkshayHazari It seems that `ensure_index` was deprecated (and removed) past or in 3.0, I do not know which is the appropriate way to perform the action past 3.0. Perhaps try just using the `create_index` method instead?

Comment: It seems that in the JavaScript API `ensureIndex` is just an alias for `createIndex` since version 3.0: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/